# Jump to video times read from external file in Html5-video

Tags: video, html5-video

I would like to see a video on a browser and be able to jump to custom times with these requirements:

- These custom times (in seconds for example) should be read from an external "times.txt" file ;
- Ideally, it would be nice to have a bar with "n" slots (n being equal to the number of times in the "times.txt" file), and that one could change slot either with the mouse or with arrows ;

How to reach or get close to that goal ? This is the closest that I have been able to do after some research :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
<video id="myvideo" width="420" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/ogg"></source>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
<div>
    <p>
        <button id="playme">Play/Pause Video</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button id="jump">Jump to 7</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
    <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
    </p>
</div>

</div> 

<script> 
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo'),
    playbutton = document.getElementById('playme'),
    jumplink = document.getElementById('jump');

jumplink.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    myvideo.play();
    myvideo.pause();
    myvideo.currentTime = 7;
    myvideo.play();
}, false);

// only in to demonstrate video
playbutton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (myvideo.paused) {
        myvideo.play();
    } else {
        myvideo.pause();
    }
}, false);

function makeBig() { 
    myvideo.width = 560; 
} 

function makeSmall() { 
    myvideo.width = 420; 
} 

</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

As you can see here:

- There is a button that makes the video jump always to 7 secs "myvideo.currentTime = 7;", but this time is hard-coded and not read from a file ;
- There is no seek bar ;

UPDATE: as per suggestion, I tried to add inside my < script > tag these lines to load data into an array variable:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('mytext.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

but in my console on the browser I see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at trial2.html:32:10
```

and I was not able at the moment to get rid of that error

Comment: Did you try anything? Lots of tutorials on how to load a text file in Javascript. Maybe separate your times (in seconds) by commas then in JS you can use that comma as a delimiter of where to extract each time (using String API's `split` function which puts results in an Array for easy usage later). For a seek-bar you can try making a `<div>` then add a colour fill to it. You can add a **click** event listen and in the handing function (_eg:_ `function on_Div_click ( evt )` you detect clicked position in X-axis as `evt.layerX;`. Use maths to ratio the Div's width against the video duration.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One regarding reading of a text file in Javascript, I tried a bit more and I think I found a possible solution, but at the moment I am getting an error I cannot get rid of. See the update.

Comment: Aha I thought it was you from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802931/sync-motion-of-graphics-with-video-in-javascript). PS: Not ignoring your comment, just that you said you were using `var fs = require('fs');` which is special to **Node JS**, a system that I'm not familiar with (I'm like what is `readFileSync` anyway?). I could only ever answer this with a "regular" Javascript version (if that's acceptable to you, and you don't specifically need NodeJS commands).

Comment: Ah ok good to know that it is not regular javascript. If I manage to find a regular javascript methodology I will update my question better... Anyway yes it is always me, I am trying to learn some javascript by doing, and my level at the moment is not that great :) thanks for your help in the process...