# Sync motion of graphics with video in Javascript

Tags: javascript, graphics, html5-video

I would like to build a small application running on browser ( using Chrome ) that synchronizes an embedded video with some graphics. I took inspiration from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AD2ciZ-0UI for a small test.

Here I am trying to play the video and "move" the position of a rectangle accordingly, in a synced way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<video id="myvideo" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
<svg id="myrect" viewBox="0 0 200 200" > <rect  x=10 y=8 width=5 height=20 
        fill-opacity=0.0 
        style="stroke-width:0.5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/> </svg>
<script>
  var m = 10 ;
  var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo')
  var rect = document.getElementById('myrect');
  myvideo.addEventListener('play', function() {
    timerID=window.setInterval(function (){
         m=parseInt(myvideo.currentTime);
         console.log(m);
         rect.setAttribute('x',m);
    },100)
  })
  </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Unluckily, when running this I see that the variable "m" gets incremented correctly (looking at the values in the Console), but the rectangle is not moving. What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE AFTER ANSWER OF @VC.ONE .**

Here is a working version from @vc.one , slighly modified. The slight modification is that the rectangle now moves below the video in a way synced to the progress bar. This method seems to work, but it looks that the rectangle follows the progress bar with some delay, especially when this is dragged fast. How to improve the responsiveness of this code ? ( I am also open to use other platforms/programs )

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <style>
body {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    } 
        </style>
    </head>
<body> 

<div> 
<video id="myvideo" width="720" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
<svg id="mysvgrect"  viewBox="0 0 200 200" > <rect id="myrect"  x=4 y=0 width=5 height=15
        fill-opacity=0.0 
        style="stroke-width:0.5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/> </svg>
</div>

<script>
var timerID;
var m = 10;
var speed = 0;
const rect = document.getElementById('myrect');
const myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
myvideo.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() { moveShape() } );
myvideo.addEventListener('play', function() { handle_Play() } );

function moveShape()
{
   speed = 188/myvideo.duration ;
    m = 4 + ( speed * (myvideo.currentTime) );
    rect.style.x = m; //# direct access to "x" Style
    //rect.setAttribute('x', m); //# alt way to access same "x" Style
}
function handle_Play()
{
    //# if needed (may clog the console with constant messages every 100 ms)
    //timerID = window.setInterval( doTimer(), 100);
}

function doTimer()
{
    m = parseInt( myvideo.currentTime );
    console.log("video secs : " + m);
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**UPDATE WITH A WORKING VERSION USING setInterval :**

After some trials I tried again with setInterval, and kind of works better I think, as far as synchronization speed is concerned :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <style>
body {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    } 
        </style>
    </head>
<body> 

<div> 
<video id="myvideo" width="720" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
<svg id="mysvgrect"  viewBox="0 0 200 200" > <rect id="myrect"  x=4 y=0 width=5 height=15
        fill-opacity=0.0 
        style="stroke-width:0.5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/> </svg>
</div>

<script>
var timerID;
var m = 10;
var speed = 0;
const rect = document.getElementById('myrect');
const myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');

setInterval(function () {
    speed = 188/myvideo.duration ;
    m = 4 + ( speed * (myvideo.currentTime) );
    rect.style.x = m; // will get you a lot more updates.
}, 30);

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

The main difference I think is that with setInterval one has more control on how frequently the function is called ( here e.g. I set up 30 ms), whereas with timeupdate I did not find this possibility. But I am not sure about the drawbacks. Please leave any comments on what you think about this solution... ( for those intereseted, also setInterval has a limit to the update frequency, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp , i.e. 10 ms )

Comment: Looking good so far. Are you trying to create your UI for video player or just sync'ing some graphic's position against video time? Cos if making a UI, you have to account for video duration as well. As for dragging on the progress bar, to sync the rectangle position with "dragging" position you have to check the mouse's position over the video. Something like `.clientX` or such. I'll update when I get a chance to double-check for you later on.

Comment: Wonderful thanks a lot for your help. I am actually trying to create a UI for video player, so that I can show some information synced with the video. But before I have to see what I am able to do with javascript, hence these tests. If you have any better idea/insight that can help speed/quality of synchronization, I can make some more tests. I am not sure I understood how you propose to use .clientX .

Comment: ( by the way, I will accept your answer, once we finished this dicussion :), I did not forget.. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Consider giving the `<rect>` element  its own unique ID to directly access it.
- Use the Video API's `timeupdate` event to move the shape against video time.

Try something like this (**ps**: notice the `rect id="myrect"` vs `svg id="mysvgrect"`) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<video id="myvideo" width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
<svg id="mysvgrect" viewBox="0 0 200 200" > <rect id="myrect" x=10 y=8 width=5 height=20 
        fill-opacity=0.0 
        style="stroke-width:0.5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/> </svg>
<script>

var timerID;
var m = 10;
var speed = 0;
const rect = document.getElementById('myrect');

const myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');
myvideo.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() { moveShape() } );
myvideo.addEventListener('play', function() { handle_Play() } );


function moveShape()
{
   speed = 9.8;
    m = 10 + ( speed * (myvideo.currentTime) );
    rect.style.x = m; //# direct access to "x" Style
    //rect.setAttribute('x', m); //# alt way to access same "x" Style
}

function handle_Play()
{
    //# if needed (may clog the console with constant messages every 100 ms)
    //timerID = window.setInterval( doTimer(), 100);
}

function doTimer()
{
    m = parseInt( myvideo.currentTime );
    console.log("video secs : " + m);
}
  
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Great answer. I still have to study properly your code, but I tried it and it seems to work. Look also at the updated question, if you have some time. As a next step I made the rectangle move below the video, synced with the time progress bar. Nevertheless, I am not 100% satisfied with the speed of syncronization. Is there something that one could do to improve it ? As I wrote, I am also open to other programs/libraries ...

Comment: ( even if I would stick to your code and javascript if possible of course )

Comment: I tried again with setInterval, what do you think ? (see updated question!)